# How to use nscache to download image from api.?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UIImageview` in `UICollectionview` cell and parse the image data from api and add to `UIImageview`. Now everything is going perfect but there is some problem I face during scroll down, when I tried to scroll `UICollectionview` cell its going hang.

Now I need to use `NSCache` to download image and than add it to `UIImage`, but I am unable to do this task I am stuck somewhere in my code, I don't know where. Please look at my code.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

OneTimeCell *cell = (OneTimeCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.selected = YES;
 [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];

cell.productname.text = [[productname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"product_name"];
cell.productnumber.text = [[productname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];


NSString *image = [[productname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image" ];
NSLog(@"image  %@", image);
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev1.brainpulse.org/ecoware1//app/webroot/img/uploads/Product/thumb/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:image relativeToURL:baseURL];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage * productimage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
NSURL *absURL = [url absoluteURL];
NSLog(@"absURL = %@", absURL);


if (productimage) {

       cell.productimage.image = productimage;
}

else
{

    cell.productimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_1.png"];


    [self.imageDownloadingQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:image relativeToURL:baseURL];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        UIImageView *image = nil;

        if (image) {

            [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:imageData];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                OneTimeCell *cell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                if (cell) {

                    cell.productimage.image = image;
                }

            }];
        }



    }];
      }




     return cell;

  }
```

Comment: NSURLSession could be helpful

Comment: ok thanks for your response

Comment: @sandeeptomar please check my code . . . You cell was stuck because you were fetching the image on main thread . . .So Please check

Comment: ok sir, but one issue is there, i am create image view in onetime cell but it gives me error

Comment: @sandeeptomar you can refer [apple demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) for LazyTableImages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code line 10 you fetching image on mainthread that is why your cell got stuck . . .Please replace that code with this one

**Replace this code**

```
NSString *image = [[productname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image" ];
NSLog(@"image  %@", image);
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev1.brainpulse.org/ecoware1//app/webroot/img/uploads/Product/thumb/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:image relativeToURL:baseURL];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage * productimage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
NSURL *absURL = [url absoluteURL];
NSLog(@"absURL = %@", absURL);
```

**With This one**

```
 NSString *image = [[productname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image" ];
NSLog(@"image  %@", image);
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev1.brainpulse.org/ecoware1//app/webroot/img/uploads/Product/thumb/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:image relativeToURL:baseURL];

dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(q, ^{

NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
UIImage * productimage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    });
});
```

Comment: should i use this code in cellfor index path method.?

Comment: use this code in cellforrow index path .. . replace your code

Comment: if i need to add default image while loading of images is complete then should i use if block for placeholder image in it?

Comment: just add a dummy image in your imageview and when your image will be fetched in background it will replace it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104150/discussion-between-anil-solanki-and-sandeep-tomar).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = @"................";

ImageRequest *request = [[ImageRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

UIImage *image = [request cachedResult];

if (image) {
     // Set the image if exist
} else {
    [request startWithCompletion:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  if(image) {
    cell.productimage.image = productimage;
   }else {
   // Set any placeholder image here.......

}
});
}];
}
```

Comment: or if you want more easy and reliable soultion then its done easily by a thijrd party library https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *image = [[productname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image" ];
NSLog(@"image  %@", image);
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev1.brainpulse.org/ecoware1//app/webroot/img/uploads/Product/thumb/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:image relativeToURL:baseURL];

dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(q, ^{

    //NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {

         if(data)
         {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 UIImage * productimage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

             });
         }
     }];
});
```

Comment: It will re download each time you scroll.

Comment: You have to check the cell's imageView. Incase if it is having image then don't do any, if not download it

Comment: It will work while image is downloaded, but while image is downloading it will keep adding new queue.

Comment: ok thanks, in my current code images are downloading while i scroll that's why i faced hang problem

Comment: Did you try my code? I am running downloading related functions in background thread. After that I am loading the imageview image on main thread. So there is no way of struck or hang. It is already in one of my AppStore app

Comment: If you want to pause/cancel kind of functionalities for image download please use the NSURLSession